# Process \hbox with luaotfload

Tags: luatex, luaotfload

I have a ‘plain’ `\hbox` with a series of glyphs which haven’t been processed with `luaoftload` (at least, not fully processed, although ideally and for for what I want they shouldn’t be processed at all), and I’d like to (re)process them in full (after some manipulations). Here is the initial test file, just to show how glyphs are remapped:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\makeatletter

\setmainfont{Amiri}

\setbox0\hbox{بِسْمِ}

\directlua{
for n in node.traverse_id(node.id('glyph'), tex.box[0].head) do 
  print('>>',
    string.format("\@percentchar x", n.char),
    n.yoffset, n.xoffset)
end
print()
}

\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\setbox0\hbox{بِسْمِ}

\directlua{
for n in node.traverse_id(node.id('glyph'), tex.box[0].head) do 
  print('>>',
    string.format("\@percentchar x", n.char),
    n.yoffset, n.xoffset)
end
}

\stop
```

The result is:

```
>>  628 0   0
>>  650 0   -425920
>>  633 0   0
>>  652 0   -289280
>>  645 0   0
>>  650 -41600  -259200

>>  f09a0   0   0
>>  650 0   -230720
>>  f09b7   0   0
>>  652 0   -305920
>>  f0b29   0   0
>>  650 0   -320640
```

The first block are still the input characters (unprocessed), and the second one is a processed node list (the first number is the 'char' field). So far so good. This is what I was expecting.

So I thought all I needed was something like:

```
tex.box[0].head = xxxx(tex.box[0].head)
```

`loadotfload` adds two function to `hpack_filter`, so they were my candidates for `xxxx`, but apparently they aren’t public (at least the function labelled `luaotfload.node_processor`).

So my question, is there a way to process an `hlist` with `luaotfload`?

Comment: aren't they both fully  processed, but in different fonts?, `\TU/Amiri(0)/m/n/10=select font Amiri:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlg;` and `\TU/Amiri(1)/m/n/10=select font Amiri:mode=node;script=arab;language=dflt;+tlig;` ? do you want to reset the first box with the latter?

Comment: Sure, technically they are, but if the script isn't `arab` there is no contextual analysis, so in practice it's incomplete.

Comment: yes but unless you change the font to one with `arab` won't luaotfload never do that analysis so you need to iterate and change the font first, not just apply an existing luaotfload function? (but don't trust me, marcel would be more  reliable:-)

Comment: This is why I said after some manipulations. Anyway, I may insert a character requiring some reprocessing, so the font is not the relevant point here.